# De-Doppler a signal: Audio Timestretch Factor controlled by function f(x)?

Tags: audio, audio-processing

Timestretching usually is constant. Few programs offer bézier handles and such to control the lead-in and lead-out. But that's all. I need better.

So the audio I have was in fact recorded in nonlinearly timestretched form, because the sound source was moving toward the microphone -- geometry, speed, and distances are all known at this point. Basically I want to "de-Doppler" the signal!

The means to take out the Doppler effect is sqrt(1+x^2), x being the ratio of linear to offset distance.

I would now like to apply that function to control the amount of stretching (NOT the stretching algorithm itself!) of the signal at any given point. That function would then serve as kind of an automation curve, only that its done algorithmically instead of by "Touch". The stretch factor could depend on the ratio "actual moment/total length".

Is this at all possible?